# Winston Logger Rotation file names increase in twos

Tags: node.js, nestjs, winston

Is there a way to get the filenames in Winston to increase by a single number each time?

Here is my config code

```js
this.logger = createLogger({
      transports: [
        new (transports.File)({
          filename: this.getFileName(),
          maxsize: rotationFileSizeMb * 1024 * 1024,
          maxFiles: rotationFileCount,
          format: format.printf(info => this.logFormatter(info)),
          level: logLevel,
        })
      ]
    });


...
...

  private getFileName(): string {
    return `${this.tgpFolder}/var/log/${this.appCode}.log`;
  }
```

I am using the "normal" File transport rather than the winston-daily-rotate-file.

My log files look like this: -

```
myApp.log
myApp1.log
myApp3.log
myApp5.log
```

This seems strange.  Have I missed a config option?

Comment: What does `this.getFileName()` look like?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel it's a fairly straightforward string substitution, I've edited the question to add it.

Comment: How does `this.appCode` get updated?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel it is passed in at startup through the command-line arguments

Comment: If that's the only way the `this.appCode` gets updated, then I can only assume your command line arguments are increasing by 2. Why? No clue.

Comment: This is during operation, the appcode remains the same, but the files are rotating after x megabytes, I would expect it to go to 1/2/3/4 instead of 2/4/6/8